# Remove white space from a string only if exceeds a certain size

Tags: c#

I've this string:

```
Corso Vittorio Emanuele II 9          20122          Milano
```

this string was initially in this format:

```
Corso Vittorio Emanuele II 9
      20122
      Milano
```

so I removed the `NewLine` using a Regex expression:

```
var stringWithoutNewLine = Regex.Replace(text, "\t|\n|\r", string.Empty).Trim();
```

now I tried to remove the whitespace in this way:

```
 return Regex.Replace(stringWithoutNewLine, @"\s+", string.Empty);
```

but it's not working as expected, 'cause I get this result:

```
CorsoVittorioEmanueleII920122Milano
```

when should be:

```
Corso Vittorio Emanuele II 9 20122 Milano
```

Comment: To be clear are you only trying to remove whitespace + newlines within the string?

Comment: Replace it with one space instead of an empty string.

Comment: You're replacing all whitespaces with `String.Empty`, I would expect this result... Replace `string.Empty` with `" "` :p

Comment: Just use the original regex and replace to one space " " instead of an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex from `@"\s+"` to `@"\s{2,}"`. It will remove whitespaces that are repeated from 2 to (kind of) infinite number. Then, as Juharr noted, replace with a space:

```
Regex.Replace(yourString, @"\s{2,}", " ");
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip!

Comment: That's not the issue.  The issue is that all the whitespace is replaced with an empty string instead of one space character.

Comment: @juharr I also tried with `" "`, instead of `string.empty` the situation is the same.

Comment: If you do `Regex.Replace("this         has        spaces", @"\s{2,}", string.Empty)` you will get "thishasspaces".  You have to replace with " " to get "this has spaces" and it works with `\s+` just as well.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to use Regex for this? Why not something like this?

```
var splitString = text.Split(new char[0],StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var stringWithoutExtraSpaces = string.Join(" ",splitString);
```

Comment: You need a check for empty strings (or that `splitString` has a length of zero) to avoid an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.  Also you could have just used `string.Join`.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I didn't think of that. Amending my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(stringWithoutNewLine, @"\s+", " "));
```